# After reading the XLSX file, in the place of the desired number, I get the numbers that are written before the coma

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, xlsx

It should show an integer, as written in the example, you can help somehow if anyone has encountered this

**This block is located in the xlsx file**

```js
SM2CKG26T2D AIR PODS ORIG 2 1,000
SMXHPD2D66V AIR PODS ORIG 3 1,000
2400000002567   ANTI LOST$  41,000
87619   ANTIRADAR 535$  4,000
```

**This is a method to read documents in nest**

```js
  createByDocument(document: Express.Multer.File) {
    const workbook = xlsx.read(document.buffer, { type: 'buffer' });
    const sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
    const sheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];

    const data: any[] = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet, { raw: true });

    const firstThreeElements = data.slice(0, 4);

    const formattedData = firstThreeElements.map((row: any) => {
      const productCode = row['Կոդ'];
      const productName = row['Անվանում'];
      const quantity = row.__EMPTY;

      if (!productCode || !productName || !quantity) {
        throw new HttpException(
          'Invalid product code or name or quantity',
          HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN,
        );
      }

      return {
        code: productCode,
        title: productName,
        count: quantity,
      };
    });
    console.log(formattedData);
  }
```

**and this is the result that I get**

```js
[
  { code: 'SM2CKG26T2D', title: 'AIR PODS ORIG 2', count: 1 },
  { code: 'SMXHPD2D66V', title: 'AIR PODS ORIG 3', count: 1 },
  { code: '2400000002567', title: 'ANTI LOST$', count: 41 },
  { code: '87619', title: 'ANTIRADAR 535$', count: 4 }
]
```

**As you can see, for example, instead of 1000 I get 1, Can someone suggest a solution**